How to implement server rendered "Read More" and "Read Less" in Next.js?
I'm facing a problem where I need to display a specific number of server components in the client through the map method, because all the necessary data is in my array. I know that if I insert a server component directly in the client environment, it will automatically become a client one, I need to avoid that.
import { serviceItems } from "@/data";
import React from "react";
import SectionHeader from "./UI/SectionHeader";
import ServiceVisibilityController from "./ServiceVisibilityController";
import ServiceCard from "./ServiceCard";

const ServicesSection = () => {
  return (
    <section id="services" className="relative mb-24">
      <SectionHeader>Service</SectionHeader>
      <ServiceVisibilityController serviceItems={serviceItems}>
        {serviceItems.map((item) => (
          <ServiceCard        //server component that I do not have to change in client
            key={item.id}
            imageSrc={item.imageSrc}
            title={item.title}
            description={item.description}
          />
        ))}
      </ServiceVisibilityController>
    </section>
  );
};

export default ServicesSection;

"use client";

import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect, Fragment } from "react";
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";
import ServiceCard from "./ServiceCard";
import RenderButton from "./RenderButton";

interface ServiceVisibilityControllerProps {
  serviceItems: {
    id: number;
    imageSrc: {
      url: string;
      alt: string;
    }[];
    title: string;
    description: string[];
  }[];
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const ServiceVisibilityController: React.FC<
  ServiceVisibilityControllerProps
> = ({ serviceItems, children }) => {
  const [visibleServices, setVisibleServices] = useState(6);
  const placeholderRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const handleShowMore = () => {
    setVisibleServices(serviceItems.length);
  };

  const handleHide = () => {
    setVisibleServices(6);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (visibleServices === 6 && placeholderRef.current) {
      placeholderRef.current.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
        block: "end",
      });
    }
  }, [visibleServices]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="md:grid md:grid-cols-2 md:gap-5 lg:grid-cols-3">
        <AnimatePresence mode="sync">
          {serviceItems.slice(0, visibleServices).map((item, index) => (
            <motion.div
              key={item.id}
              className="scroll-mb-[150px]"
              initial={{ opacity: 0, y: 20 }}
              animate={{ opacity: 1, y: 0 }}
              exit={{ opacity: 0, y: -20 }}
              transition={{ delay: index * 0.05 }}
              ref={index === 5 ? placeholderRef : null}
            >
              {children}
            </motion.div>
          ))}
        </AnimatePresence>
      </div>
      {visibleServices < serviceItems.length ? (
        <RenderButton onClick={handleShowMore} text="Показати більше" />
      ) : (
        <RenderButton onClick={handleHide} text="Сховати" />
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default ServiceVisibilityController;

The above code is incorrect because there are two map methods (one in ServiceSection and a second one in ServiceVisibility) this causes duplicate services. I've tried many options, such as passing the server component through props to the client component.

Is your route dynamic (not "force-static")?

No, I'm developing a landing page, if that's what you mean

Is your page rendered on every request (SSR) or is it statically rendered (SSG/ISR)?

It is statically rendered (ISR)

You can render server components with lazy loading (next/dynamic).
Stackblitz demo
page.tsx:
import Service from './service';
import Wrapper from './wrapper';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main>
      <Wrapper
        count={20}
        initialServices={Array.from({ length: 6 }).map((_, i) => (
          <Service key={i} idx={i} />
        ))}
      />
    </main>
  );
}

wrapper.tsx:
'use client';

import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import { Fragment, useState } from 'react';

const Service = dynamic(() => import('./service'), {
  loading: () => <>Loading...</>,
});

export default function Wrapper({
  initialServices,
  count,
}: {
  initialServices: React.ReactNode[];
  count: number;
}) {
  const [visibleServices, setVisibleServices] = useState(
    initialServices.length
  );

  return (
    <>
      <p>Showing {visibleServices} services.</p>
      <div className="flex grid grid-cols-2 gap-3">
        {initialServices.map((service, i) => (
          // Use id not i as key!
          <Fragment key={i}>{service}</Fragment>
        ))}
        {Array.from({ length: visibleServices - initialServices.length })
          .map((_, i) => (
            <Service key={i} idx={initialServices.length + i} />
          ))}
      </div>
      <button
        className="bg-blue-300 p-3 cursor-pointer"
        onClick={() => {
          if (visibleServices === count) {
            setVisibleServices(initialServices.length);
          } else {
            setVisibleServices(count);
          }
        }}
      >
        {visibleServices === count ? 'Show less' : 'Show more'}
      </button>
    </>
  );
}

service.tsx:
export default async function Service({ idx }: { idx: number }) {
  return (
    <div className="size-[200px] bg-red-400 inline-block p-5">
      I'm rendered on the server #{idx}
    </div>
  );
}

This is just an example, use your id field (not index) as the key and to fetch the data for each item on your server.

I occured a error: Cannot update a component (Router) while rendering a different component (proxy). To locate the bad setState() call inside proxy, follow the stack trace as described

Can you fork the stackblitz and reproduce the error? Is the error related to the anser? If not you should open a new question
